# Is it safe for me to drive home?

Tags: honda, sparkplugs, fit

I have a 2009 Honda Fit, I had the spark plugs replaced but I’ve been having trouble with the 4th cylinder. I got it looked at two weeks ago but now it’s doing it again. My car smells of gas and there’s no sign of a leak. From what I’ve read online it’s the spark plug. I’m just wondering if it’s safe for me to drive home with it like that. I’m about 268 miles away from home.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid driving this as it can cause additional damage to the engine.  The excess fuel gets "catalyzed" in the catalytic converter and that can literally melt it.  A new cat is expensive!  It can also cause high exhaust back pressure that can damage other engine components.

Your best bet is to have it towed to your home or have it fixed where it is.

Comment: A thousand times this - driving the car would be one way to turn a potentially minor, easily fixed issue into a big, expensive catastrophe.